Global Position and TileMap Position not Updating
Currently using "Godot 4.2.2" and "C#". I've been setting up a game to use keyboard controls and no mouse controls. I am trying to get my player character's location when the "Enter" key is pressed. It will return the global and "TileMap" position of where the player spawns, but never updates the player's position as my player moves across the "TileMap" when the scene is running. hen I run the project, the print statements show that "PRESS_COUNT" is updating, and the tile near where the player character spawns does change after pressing "Enter" twice, but if I move the character to a different spot on the
TileMap", the positions the print statements return are the same:

Player's global position: (585, 157)
"TileMap" position: (18, 4).

I don't know where I went wrong.
This is my current script:
using System;

public partial class FarmingScene : Node2D
{
    [Export]
    private TileMap tilemap;

    private int PRESS_COUNT = 0;


    public override void _PhysicsProcess(double delta)
    {

        PlayerCharacter playerCharacter = GetNode<PlayerCharacter>("PlayerCharacter");
     

        if (Input.IsActionJustPressed("INTERACT"))
        {
            PRESS_COUNT++;

            Vector2 playerGlobalPosition = playerCharacter.GlobalPosition;

            GD.Print("Player's global position: ", playerGlobalPosition);


            if (tilemap == null)
            {
                GD.PrintErr("Tilemap is not assigned.");
                return;
            }

            Vector2I tileMapPosition = tilemap.LocalToMap(playerGlobalPosition);

            GD.Print("Tilemap position: ", tileMapPosition);  

            if (PRESS_COUNT == 1)
            {   GD.Print("Hit Enter Once");

                Vector2I tilledAtlasCoordinates = new Vector2I(7, 1);
               
                tilemap.SetCell(0, tileMapPosition, 2, tilledAtlasCoordinates);
            }
            else if (PRESS_COUNT == 2)
            {
                GD.Print("Hit Enter Twice");

                Vector2I wateredAtlasCoordinates = new Vector2I(7, 4);


                tilemap.SetCell(0, tileMapPosition, 2, wateredAtlasCoordinates);
            }
            else
            {
                GD.Print(PRESS_COUNT);
            }
        }
    }
}


I figured it out. It was related to the way I set up my PlayerCharacter scene. The coordinates the print statements were returning were the same location of my player character's pivot point. I have just added a small Area2D to the front of my player character and use that for interaction detection and it works fine.
